# JAVA getResourceAsStream() real path string interpretation of a file

Tags: java, path, stream, getresource

I am using NetBeans 8.0.2 (I know there already is v8.2 but it has a lot of bugs for me so I got back to v8.0.2) and I need a string path to my .obj file for a parameter attribute like this:

```
api.parameter("filename", "obj/someFile.obj");
```

Above example worked in a previous version of my app where I had that .obj file placed in a folder called "obj" in the same directory as my .jar file, but now as I am trying to rather include it in the JAR itself with code:

```
api.parameter("filename", MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/someFile.obj").toString());
```

...it is not working anymore as the path string interpretation is not a path to a file, it looks more like this:

```
java.io.BufferedInputStream@215d7ea7
```

...where, of course, my code is expecting something like normal path string, I would said something in this pseudo-code manner:

```
api.parameter("filename", "<this.jar>/someFile.obj");
```

So after a fiddling a bit around StackOverflow I've found pieces of code that I thought could actually enable me to directly place that path as a string:

```
URL jar = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
api.parameter("filename", jar + "/someFile.obj");
```

But surprisingly although I checked several times if the file actually really exist in my built jar file (and yes, it is there in the root) it still gives me this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\Z:\_JAVA_\MyProject_0_018\dist\bin\myjar.jar\someFile.obj <The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect>
```

And I am 100% sure the name of the file is correct, also its placement in the root of my jar file.

Or does it actually thinks that `myjar.jar` is a directory?

I am desperately trying to find a solution to this "path string" mess.

Answer (score 0):

Your protection domain's code source location likely returns not what you'd expect it to.

You should use `getResource(name)` directly, like this:

```
URL locator = MyClass.class.getResource("someFile.obj");
api.parameter("filename", locator.toString());
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work - it is giving me `NullPointerException` all the time - that was actually the exact reason why I used `getResourceAsStream()` instead...

Comment: Anyway I solved it already some time ago a bit differently further in my code in a destination method where that `getResourceAsStream()` works just nice without any problem... ;-)

Comment: @theoneiam can you please share how you solved this issue, ? i am also running into similar one

Comment: @AmolBais, you're not supposed to refer to internal jarfile resources as if the jarfile is a directory and those resources are files in it. You need to ask your jar's classloader for resources, and if your classloader can't find it, then this means you either aren't providing the correct path to a resource, or there's no such resource packaged. You can consult the javadoc of relevant methods for further instructions.